# Unable to run Forge Gem/Rack Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rack

I tried installing [Forge](http://forge.thethemefoundry.com/) on my MBP, OS 10.8.2.  I already have installed Compass, Susy, Sass, and other gems so I'm used to it.

However, the install first failed saying it needed Rack installed.  So, I installed Rack and it seems to have installed successfully.

Now I tried to create a Forge project but get this error:

```
[~/Documents/.../ONOTW/onotw_wk] $ forge create onotw
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:230:in `activate': can't activate rack (~> 1.3.5, runtime) for ["forge-0.5.0"], already activated rack-1.4.1 for ["sprockets-2.0.4", "forge-0.5.0"] (Gem::LoadError)
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:246:in `activate'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:245:in `each'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:245:in `activate'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1056:in `gem'
from /usr/bin/forge:18
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and found the solution [here](https://github.com/thethemefoundry/forge/issues/56). Essentially you have two versions of rack installed and need to uninstall the conflicting version.

```
$ sudo gem uninstall rack

Select gem to uninstall:
1. rack-1.3.10
2. rack-1.4.1
3. All versions

$ 2

Successfully uninstalled rack-1.4.1
```